# Azure ML web service input parameters

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-web-app-service, azure-machine-learning-service, input-parameters

I have an experiment created in **Azure ML**, where I have a **dataset** which consists of following columns:

```
Temperature, Timestamp, Kw_system, Powerscout etc.
```

I need to input a range of timestamp say, **from Oct 1st to Oct 2nd** **and all the rows between this needs to be displayed** on which I would do anomaly detection. Please let me know how to go about it

Answer (score 2):

In Azure ML studio there's an option to do SQL transformation for the dataset. You can write a simple SQL query that selects the required data between specific time stamps and use that for the rest of process.

Do write your SQL query in the box 
[image]